# Java Classes and interface implementation

Tags: java

I am a beginner java programmer learning step by step how to code with Java.

I have this code that is an implementation of an interface in java.

Please assist me in debugging it.

Here is the interface:

```
package ke.munyiri.me;

public interface Hp {
    public void scrollUp (int increment);
    public void scrollDown (int decrement);
    public void rightClick();
    public void leftClick ();

}
```

and here is its implementation:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package ke.munyiri.me;

/**
 * @author MUNYIRI
 *
 */
public abstract class Mouse implements Hp {
    char manufacturer;
    char type;
    static int scroll;
    boolean click;


    public static void main(String[] args){

     public void scrollUp(int increment){
        scroll = scroll + increment;
        System.out.println("The mouse is scrolling up");
        }
        public  void scrollDown (int decrement){
             int scrollDown = scroll - decrement;
             System.out.println("The mouse is scrolling down");
        }


        public void rightClick(){
            boolean rightClick = true;  
            System.out.println("The mouse is right Clicking");
        }
        public leftClick(){
            boolean leftClick = true;
            System.out.println("The mouse is left Clicking");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the "problem"? (Well, trivially the main method isn't closed when it ought to be, but.. make sure to include an accurate and precise problem description, including error messages.)

Comment: @Peter what is the issue you are facing

Comment: His code doesn't compile, that's the problem

Comment: No need to put public as access modifier in interface. By default all are public.

Comment: Please put the relevant error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compile errors in your code. You can't declare methods inside a another method. In your code You have override interface methods inside your main method. Take them out of the main method scope. Like this

```
public abstract class Mouse implements Hp {
    char manufacturer;
    char type;
    static int scroll;
    boolean click;

    public static void main(String[] args){
    }

    public void scrollUp(int increment){
        scroll = scroll + increment;
        System.out.println("The mouse is scrolling up");
    }
    public  void scrollDown (int decrement){
        int scrollDown = scroll - decrement;
        System.out.println("The mouse is scrolling down");
    }

    public void rightClick(){
        boolean rightClick = true;  
        System.out.println("The mouse is right Clicking");
    }

    public void leftClick(){
        boolean leftClick = true;
        System.out.println("The mouse is left Clicking");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also comment the fact that the `static scroll` is probably an error to be especially if multiple `Mouse` (subclass) instance are created.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in your code. You can't declare another `method` inside a `method`.

Change your structure

```
public MyClass implements MyInterface{

  public static void main(String[] args){

  }
  public void myMethod1(){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you defined an Interface and an abstract class but no concrete class. Your implementation can't be used on it's own but requires a further 'implementation' class *or* you could remove the `abstract` keyword from your class definition. This keyword isn't needed as you don't have any abstract methods in your class.

Well and as others have pointed out, your main method (which you don't need) misses it's closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Before Learning the concept of interface , You should have to learn basic . i.e you **cannot have methods implemented inside another method**, And to Know about interface first you should have knowledge about what is Abstract and Concrete.

**ABSTRACT CLASS**

```
public abstract class GraphicObject {
  // declare fields
  // declare nonabstract methods
  abstract void draw();
  }
```

An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

An abstract method is a method that is declared without an implementation.

**CONCRETE CLASS**

An abstract class is meant to be used as the base class from which other classes are derived. The derived class is expected to provide implementations for the methods that are not implemented in the base class. A derived class that implements all the missing functionality is called a concrete class .

```
public class Graph implements GraphicObject{
public void draw()
{
//defination
}
```